# ng-repeat for input template with multiple types

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am making a user interface to add to and edit a database. I am using breeze to manage the database, angular grid for the display and a ui-bootstrap modal dialog for the user input. When I set the type="" on the input tag, I cannot complete input all the information. If type="text" then an error is thrown for my primary key, which is a number. If type="number" then most of my other inputs are not accepted. I believe I have text, number, and datetime to input. Is there a good, straightforward way to implement multiple types in my template? I am about to give up and just enter the key only then have users add the rest in the table.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in newRow">
        <label>{{key | uppercase}}</label>
        <input placeholder="Enter &quot;{{key}}&quot; value"
            class="form-control"
            type="number"
            ng-model="newRow[key]" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class to return "text", "number", etc.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in newRow" ng-class="{text:checkDataType(), number:checkDataType()}">
        <label>{{key | uppercase}}</label>
        <input placeholder="Enter &quot;{{key}}&quot; value"
            class="form-control"
            type="number"
            ng-model="newRow[key]" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

I'm not sure if you have a way of finding out the data type from the data you're getting, so I put checkDataType() instead, as a filler. If you do have a way of finding out the data type you can just set it equal to a string, accordingly. If not, you will have to create the checkDataType() function and write some js. Let me know if you have questions or if you need examples. Good luck!